# How to use if statement between parameters in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there any possibility to use an if statement between parameters in Jenkinsfile something like below :

I used Active Choice plugin so I am not looking for that solution

```
properties([
        parameters([
            choice(
                name: 'option1',
                choices: [ "1", "2" ]
            ),              
            if (option1.equal("1"){
                choice(
                    name: 'option2',
                    choices: [ "3", "4" ]
                )
            }
        ])
])
```

Comment: You can't use conditions inside the parameters directive. To achieve what you want you will need to use a special plugin that allows this functionality like the [Active Choices Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used Active Choice plugin so I am not looking for that solution

Apart from impossibility to use conditions [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78228495/how-to-use-if-statement-between-parameters-in-jenkinsfile#comment137917357_78228495) by Noah Helmer in the comments, there is no way to do that without the external plugins because of the Jenkins architecture - it does not evaluate the Jenkinsfile before running the build.

All that you can see in Jenkins UI when you click the `Build with parameters` button is the result of the **previous** build that loaded the previous version of your Jenkinsfile. It will still apply even if you use Active Choices or another plugin.